# how to solve Unhandled Exception: Converting object to an encodable object failed?

Tags: flutter, local-storage, flutter-getx

I created 2  classes the first one is :

```
class Mesure {
  late String equipement; 
  late String number; 
  late String courant = ""; 
  

  Mesure.init(List<String> values) {
    equipement = values[0];
    number = values[1];
    courant = values[2];
    
  }

}
```

and DataBase class :

```
class DataBase {
  late int? id;
  late Mesure? mesure;
  late String? status;
  DataBase.init(int id, Mesure mesure, String status) {
    id = id;
    mesure = mesure;
    status = status;
  }
}
```

Now i initialized DataBase with some values  :

```
  Mesure mesure = Mesure.init(values);
  DataBase test = DataBase.init(0, mesure, "status");
```

and i want to store it in storage getX :

```
   final box = GetStorage();
  box.write('data', test);
```

but it does not work and throw an exception :

> E/flutter (19759): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)]
> Unhandled Exception: Converting object to an encodable object failed:
> Instance of 'DataBase'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`get_storage`](https://pub.dev/packages/get_storage) package uses [`json.encode`](https://github.com/jonataslaw/get_storage/blob/28d0a4eba1ec5a52fb09f98d9ba56db70683f706/lib/src/storage/io.dart#L92) and [`json.decode`](https://github.com/jonataslaw/get_storage/blob/28d0a4eba1ec5a52fb09f98d9ba56db70683f706/lib/src/storage/io.dart#L34) to save and load data from a file. And [`json.encode`](https://api.dart.dev/be/175791/dart-convert/jsonEncode.html)/[`json.decode`](https://api.dart.dev/be/175791/dart-convert/jsonDecode.html) documentation says that it can only serialize/deserialize classes if the `toJson` and `fromJson` functions are implemented respectively.

So, the code is going to look like this:

```dart
class Mesure {
  late String equipement;
  late String number;
  late String courant = "";

  Mesure.init(List<String> values) {
    equipement = values[0];
    number = values[1];
    courant = values[2];
  }

  Mesure.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : equipement = json['equipement'],
        number = json['number'],
        courant = json['courant'];

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'equipement': equipement,
      'number': number,
      'courant': courant,
    };
  }
}

class DataBase {
  final int id;
  final Mesure mesure;
  final String status;
  DataBase.init(this.id, this.mesure, this.status);

  DataBase.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : id = json['id'],
        mesure = Mesure.fromJson(json['mesure']),
        status = json['status'];

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'mesure': mesure.toJson(),
      'status': status,
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: hello thanks for response , i have a similar problem to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72830170/unhandled-exception-converting-object-to-an-encodable-object-failed-instance-o can u help me ..  my probelm is how to do if i must add some data and i wanted to be jump it  when i don't have them thanks in advance

Comment: I'm going to check it...

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
class DataBase {
  int? id;
  Mesure? mesure;
  String? status;
  DataBase(this.id, this.mesure, this.status);
}
```

Then use

```
Mesure mesure = Mesure.init(values);
DataBase test = DataBase(id:0, mesure : mesure, status:"status");
```

Comment: it shows the same errors