# Unhandled Exception: Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'Mesure'

Tags: flutter

hello i have the class mesure when i read data i use it ass a model then i save it on my database getstorage getX . it works perfectly , but when i add this test if mode = display i 'm going to add more data on my model and do the mapping . i'm getting this error . is it possible to skip "debut" and "fin" if it does not available ?

> Unhandled Exception: Converting object to an encodable object failed:
> Instance of 'Mesure'
> how can i fix it !!

```
class Mesure {
  late int id;
  String status;
  late String mode;
  late String equipementNumero;
  late String temperature;
  late String courant = "";
  late String debut;
  late String fin = "";

  Mesure.init(List<String> values, this.id, this.status) {
    mode = values[0];
    equipementNumero = values[1];
    temperature = values[2];
    courant = values[3];

    if (mode == "display") {
      debut = values[4];
      fin = values[5];
    }
  }

  Mesure.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : id = json['id'],
        status = json['status'],
        mode = json['mode'],
        temperature = json['temperature'],
        equipementNumero = json['equipementNumero'],
        courant = json['courant'],
        debut = json['debut'],
        fin = json['fin'];

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    if (mode == "display") {
      return {
        'id': id,
        'status': status,
        'mode': mode,
        'temperature': temperature,
        'equipementNumero': equipementNumero,
        'courant': courant,
      };
    } else {
      return {
        'id': id,
        'status': status,
        'mode': mode,
        'temperature': temperature,
        'equipementNumero': equipementNumero,
        'courant': courant,
        'debut': debut,
        'fin': fin,
      };
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 things:

1. You have to initialize `debut` to make it write to JSON ([get_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/get_storage));
2. And, you have to default the values of `debut` and `fin` to something when reading from JSON (get_storage);

So, the entire class `Mesure` would look like this:

```dart
class Mesure {
  late int id;
  String status;
  late String mode;
  late String equipementNumero;
  late String temperature;
  late String courant;
  late String debut = "";
  late String fin = "";

  Mesure.init(List<String> values, this.id, this.status) {
    mode = values[0];
    equipementNumero = values[1];
    temperature = values[2];
    courant = values[3];

    if (mode == "display") {
      debut = values[4];
      fin = values[5];
    }
  }

  Mesure.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : id = json['id'],
        status = json['status'],
        mode = json['mode'],
        temperature = json['temperature'],
        equipementNumero = json['equipementNumero'],
        courant = json['courant'],
        debut = json['debut'] ?? '',
        fin = json['fin'] ?? '';

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    if (mode == "display") {
      return {
        'id': id,
        'status': status,
        'mode': mode,
        'temperature': temperature,
        'equipementNumero': equipementNumero,
        'courant': courant,
      };
    } else {
      return {
        'id': id,
        'status': status,
        'mode': mode,
        'temperature': temperature,
        'equipementNumero': equipementNumero,
        'courant': courant,
        'debut': debut,
        'fin': fin,
      };
    }
  }
}
```

Also, the code in the constructor looks inverted in `toJson`. Shouldn't in the constructor be like this `mode != "display"` instead of `mode == "display"`:

```dart
  Mesure.init(List<String> values, this.id, this.status) {
    mode = values[0];
    equipementNumero = values[1];
    temperature = values[2];
    courant = values[3];

    if (mode != "display") {
      debut = values[4];
      fin = values[5];
    }
  }
```